# ViewPager crashes after run and while I press new activity

Tags: java, android

When I'm going from one activity (which has a Viewager inside and scrollview) to another activity then the app crashed. I think that the ViewPager works properly but the call back system isn't perfect.

Code View pager in main

```
    package com.sonalirod.run6;

import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class potovumi extends AppCompatActivity {
  ViewPager viewPager;
    ScreenshotsAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.potovumi);

        viewPager =(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.scr);
        adapter =new ScreenshotsAdapter(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

**AdapterCode**

```
   package com.sonalirod.run6;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;



public class ScreenshotsAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private int[] image_resources ={
            R.drawable.pot1,
            R.drawable.pot2,
            R.drawable.pot3,
    };


    private Context ctx;

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    public ScreenshotsAdapter (Context ctx){

        this.ctx=ctx;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return image_resources.length;
    }



    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container,int position){

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View item_view =layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.screenshots,container,false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_slider);
        imageView.setImageResource(image_resources[position]);
        container.addView(item_view);
        return item_view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container,int position,Object object)
    {

        container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view == object);

    }



}
```

Please help

**logcat**

```
05-20 19:41:04.362 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8413K, 23% free 68639K/88288K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
05-20 19:41:04.362 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 I/dalvikvm-heap: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 28336144-byte allocation
05-20 19:41:04.392 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 D/dalvikvm: GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 10K, 23% free 68628K/88288K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
05-20 19:41:04.392 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 28336144-byte allocation.
05-20 19:41:04.392 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 I/dalvikvm: "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
05-20 19:41:04.392 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 I/dalvikvm:   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x41566cc0 self=0x4147d720
05-20 19:41:04.392 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 I/dalvikvm:   | sysTid=14317 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1073840468
05-20 19:41:04.392 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 I/dalvikvm:   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=1385 stm=109 core=3
05-20 19:41:04.392 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 I/dalvikvm:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
05-20 19:41:04.402 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 I/dalvikvm:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:629)
05-20 19:41:04.402 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 I/dalvikvm:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:456)
05-20 19:41:04.402 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 I/dalvikvm:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
05-20 19:41:04.402 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 I/dalvikvm:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2268)
05-20 19:41:04.402 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 I/dalvikvm:     at com.huawei.android.content.res.ResourcesEx.loadDrawable(ResourcesEx.java:632)
05-20 19:41:04.402 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 I/dalvikvm:     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:750)
05-20 19:41:04.402 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable(ResourcesWrapper.java:128)
05-20 19:41:04.402 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.getDrawable(TintResources.java:45)
05-20 19:41:04.402 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:374)
05-20 19:41:04.402 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:202)
05-20 19:41:04.402 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:190)
05-20 19:41:04.402 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
05-20 19:41:04.402 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:73)
05-20 19:41:04.402 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:81)
05-20 19:41:04.402 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 I/dalvikvm:     at com.sonalirod.run6.ScreenshotsAdapter.instantiateItem(ScreenshotsAdapter.java:41)
05-20 19:41:04.402 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:1034)
05-20 19:41:04.402 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1248)
05-20 19:41:04.402 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
05-20 19:41:04.402 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:273)
05-20 19:41:04.412 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 I/dalvikvm:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
05-20 19:41:04.412 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 I/dalvikvm:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
05-20 19:41:04.412 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 I/dalvikvm:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
05-20 19:41:04.412 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 I/dalvikvm:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
05-20 19:41:04.412 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 I/dalvikvm:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-20 19:41:04.412 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 I/dalvikvm:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-20 19:41:04.412 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 I/dalvikvm:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-20 19:41:04.412 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5421)
05-20 19:41:04.412 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 19:41:04.412 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-20 19:41:04.412 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 I/dalvikvm:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:979)
05-20 19:41:04.412 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 I/dalvikvm:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:795)
05-20 19:41:04.412 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 I/dalvikvm:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-20 19:41:04.412 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 D/skia: --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
05-20 19:41:04.412 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-20 19:41:04.412 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41565bc0)
05-20 19:41:04.412 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: com.sonalirod.run6, PID: 14317
                                                                    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
                                                                        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:629)
                                                                        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:456)
                                                                        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
                                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2268)
                                                                        at com.huawei.android.content.res.ResourcesEx.loadDrawable(ResourcesEx.java:632)
                                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:750)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable(ResourcesWrapper.java:128)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.getDrawable(TintResources.java:45)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:374)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:202)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:190)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:73)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:81)
                                                                        at com.sonalirod.run6.ScreenshotsAdapter.instantiateItem(ScreenshotsAdapter.java:41)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:1034)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1248)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:273)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5421)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:979)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:795)
                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-20 19:41:04.422 14317-14317/com.sonalirod.run6 E/AndroidRuntime: There is a OOM!
```

Comment: Please provide the stacktrace?

Comment: add logcat, its faster for us to find errors

Comment: Maybe the issue you are facing is with your second "Activity", not with this one. Can you post the specific error or the "LogCat" results? So that I can help you track the issue.

Comment: how can i insert the cat file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `imageView.setImageResource(image_resources[position])`  in your `ScreenshotsAdapter#instantiateItem` causing `OutOfMemoryException` either your images are too big or you are doing it more often.

```
public static int calculateInSampleSizeUsingPower2(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;
    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;
        // calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth)
            inSampleSize *= 2;
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res,
        int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSizeUsingPower2(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

Replace this line `imageView.setImageResource(image_resources[position])` with

```
int reqHeight = 500; // we will use this or similer to this value to prevent OOM.
int reqWidth = 500; // we will use this or similer to this value to prevent OOM.

imageView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), image_resources[position], reqWidth, reqWidth));
```

Or use any image loading library like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

```
Picasso.with(context).load(image_resources[position]).placeholder(YOUR_PLACE_HOLDER_OR_LEAVE_EMPTY).into(imageView);
```

Comment: after doing all these the getResources() showing an error. that line where you told me to replace

Comment: the second method is work beautifully . i just download that dependency. just lil bit confuse about "placeholder" actually what does it mean? if i'm gonna live that empty than it show a error but if i'm give a  ref of an image then it works fine . 
actually i don't want give any image ref then what to do with this placeholder?!

Comment: Use `Context.getResources()` in your adapter class. Placeholder is actually default image it could be `R.drawable.any_image_refrence`.